# Installing Polymer through bower freezes

Tags: ubuntu, bower, polymer, ubuntu-14.04

I follow [the instructions of the official page](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html) to install bower, but when I reach to the command line:

```
bower install --save Polymer/core-elements
```

bower get stuck and outputs nothing for a long while, in the end I get a "out of memory" error. What is wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a cyclical issue with Bower that's been fixed on master but hasn't made it to a release yet. https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1169

Comment: I've had _some_ luck nuking my bower_components folder and reissuing `bower install`

Comment: This should be fixed in Bower 1.3.4

Answer (score 4):

according to http://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1324 there is a workaround.

edit bower.json by adding in a line so the dependency area looks like this

```
dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#~0.3.1", 
    "core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements"
  }
```

then run $ bower update

you can add other packages, too.

I'm actually brand new to polymer (had trouble installing it, as you can imagine) so I'm not positive this works.

Comment: editing bower.json and running update worked for me when install hung with bower 1.3.8